# When running $PWD/filename.sh is working correctly but having a error on running ./filename.sh

Tags: shell, sh, redhat

When I run `$PWD/filename.sh` it is running correctly but when I run `./filename.sh` I get the error

```
could not find or load main class
```

Can anyone explain why and how to make it work with `./filename.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# bash script here
SCRIPTDIR=`dirname $0`
Example_HOME=/opt/example/example
export CENTRASITE_HOME

. ${Example_HOME}/bin/example_setenv.sh

#set -xv

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# extend PATH where to find executables
#
PATH=$PATH:$CENTRASITE_HOME/install
PATH=$PATH:$CENTRASITE_HOME/bin
export PATH

# extend the Java option settings
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
export JAVA_OPTS

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

MY_HOME=$Example_HOME/bin/cfg

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# add cfg directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc.
#

#Solaris
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+":"}$MY_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

#HP-UX
SHLIB_PATH=${SHLIB_PATH:-}${SHLIB_PATH:+":"}$MY_HOME
export SHLIB_PATH

#AIX51
LIBPATH=${LIBPATH:-}${LIBPATH:+":"}$MY_HOME
export LIBPATH

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# set CLASSPATH
#
RED=${Example_HOME}/red
CLASSPATH="$RED:$RED/*"
RT_PATH=${Example_HOME}/rt/bin

LOCAL_CLASSPATH="${SCRIPTDIR}/lib/*:${CENTRASITE_HOME}/lib/*:${RTS_PATH}/*:${REDIST}/*"
export CLASSPATH

#
### parameter handling
#
PROG=`basename $0`
ERROR=0

CLASS="main.com.example"
export CLASS`enter code here`

UI=${Example_HOME}/cast/

classpath=$CLASSPATH
localclasspath=$LOCAL_CLASSPATH

#
# Always change to an existing working directory to avoid Java error

WORKDIR=`pwd`
cd $CENTRASITE_HOME
EXECUTABLE="${CS_JAVA_EXE}"
EXECUTABLE="$EXECUTABLE ${JAVA_OPTS} -cp"
EXECUTABLE="$EXECUTABLE ${LOCAL_CLASSPATH} ${CLASS}"

#  $EXECUTABLE "$@"
$EXECUTABLE "$UI $@"
#$EXECUTABLE "$UI $@"
RC=$?

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cd $WORKDIR

exit $RC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
SCRIPTDIR=`dirname $0`
```

uses `$PWD` as `SCRIPTDIR` when the program is started with `$PWD/filename.sh` and uses `.` as `SCRIPTDIR` when it is started with `./filename.sh`.  It then sets `LOCAL_CLASSPATH` using `$SCRIPTDIR` as one of the directories. Unfortunately, later on the program does:

```
cd $CENTRASITE_HOME
```

That means that with the absolute pathname, using `$SCRIPTDIR` is still valid, but using `.` completely breaks the location of `$SCRIPTDIR`.

You need to determine the absolute pathname of `$SCRIPTDIR` regardless of how it is invoked (the case where there is no path will be entertaining).

---

These lines are puzzling:

```
Example_HOME=/opt/example/example
export CENTRASITE_HOME
```

There's room to think the same name should be used on both lines; given the rest of the script, `Example_HOME` should probably be `CENTRASITE_HOME`, though both names are used quite extensively.

---

The line:

```
cd $WORKDIR
```

just before the end is pointless on Unix (not on Windows in a DOS batch command file, but this isn't a DOS batch command file).  The `cd` operations in a script do not affect the parent process that invokes the script unless you use `. filename.sh` or (in Bash) `source filename.sh`.